# Can not Connect to a database on Redshift in R by RODBC package

Tags: mysql, r, amazon-redshift, rodbc, data-science

I am trying to connect to A DB on Redshift in r  using following syntax (I am using a Mac):

```
odbcConnect("xxxxaddresss.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439", uid = "xxxx", pwd = "xxxx")
```

and get the following errors.

Warning messages:

> 1: In
>   RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=xxxxaddresss.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxx")
>   :   [RODBC] ERROR: state IM012, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver
>   Manager]DRIVER keyword syntax error
>
> 2: In
>   RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=xxxxaddresss.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxx")
>   :
>
> ODBC connection failed

What is the reason of the problem?

Comment: Did you try specifying a driver? [This](https://dreamtolearn.com/ryan/data_analytics_viz/92) may be helpful.

Comment: @nrussell Not actually how can i do that?